# Doubt regarding a simple electromechanical system

Tags: electromagnetism

My book describes a simple electromechanical system.

[image]

Here O corresponds to unstretched spring.It is assumed that magnetic material is highly permeable and clearence at point M is negligible. The book states that in A when the extension in spring is x the movable member experiences a force in such a direction that the energy stored in the field tends to increase so it reaches B with an additional displacement dx.

I couldn't get why the force experienced is such that to increase the energy stored and how decrease in air gap leads to this.In fact decrease in air gap should lead to increase in permeance so that energy stored should decrease.

Answer (score 1):

> In fact decrease in air gap should lead to increase in permeance so
>   that energy stored should decrease

With AC excitation, if the core permeance increases then the winding inductance also increases. This means that the impedance to the AC excitation is greater and this reduces current. Given that a linear increase in inductance produces a linear fall in excitation current, then the stored energy in the magnetic field is reduced because of: -

W = \$\dfrac{LI^2}{2}\$

However, for a DC excitation, it can be assumed that the coil current is held constant and therefore, because inductance increases as the movable member closes the gap, magnetic energy stored increases with L increasing.

Comment: Thanks.but sir is it not true that magnetic energy is stored in regions of high reluctance.so if the reluctance decreases magnetic energy should decrease.

Comment: @user471651 It is true but you are missing the point. For an AC excitation, a bigger gap means less inductance and therefore more current and therefore more energy is stored as per the formula I quoted. For DC excitation current is fixed hence, if inductance increases it has no effect on the fixed current flowing therefore energy increases as per the extremely well-known formula I quoted.

Comment: But in case of DC excitation when we calculate the energy stored at in magnetic field we take only the air gap inductance into account which is less than that of the core.so more energy should be stored in the core than the air gap.

Comment: Please define what air-gap inductance means?